# Start background process from TeamCity build step

Tags: teamcity

When I try to start a background process from my `Custom Script` Step Runner in TeamCity, I see that it terminates the background process as soon as the step completes. Is there a way to keep the background process running?

Here's what I am trying to do in my step:

```
ORACLE_POD_NAME=`...complex logic here...`

oc port-forward $ORACLE_POD_NAME 15210:1521 &
PORT_FORWARD_PID=$!

echo $PORT_FORWARD_PID > port_forward.pid
```

The idea is to create a persistent port forward to my OpenShift pod for the duration of the build, b/c many subsequent build steps will need it. I would then kill the port forward process using the PID I wrote into the file.

Unfortunately `oc port-forward` is terminated as soon as the step ends. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to disconnect the inputs and outputs of the background subprocess I am launching from the parent process, and tell the subprocess not to respond to `HUP (hangup)` signal.

```
nohup oc port-forward $ORACLE_POD_NAME 15210:1521 > /dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &
PORT_FORWARD_PID=$!
```

This ensures that the port-forward process survives TeamCity step termination, thus making port-forwarding available to subsequent build steps.